# Python Decimal - multiplication by zero

Tags: python, decimal, arithmetic-expressions

Why does the following code:

```
from decimal import Decimal
result = Decimal('0') * Decimal('0.8881783462119193534061639577')
print(result)
```

return **0E-28** ?

I've traced it to the following code in the [module](https://github.com/python/cpython/edit/main/Lib/_pydecimal.py):

```
if not self or not other:
    ans = _dec_from_triple(resultsign, '0', resultexp)
    # Fixing in case the exponent is out of bounds
    ans = ans._fix(context)
    return ans
```

The code appears to follow [Decimal Arithmetic Specification](https://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refmult), which doesn't explicitly suggest what to do when we multiply by zero, referring to 'special numbers' from [another standard](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/27840), which also doesn't specify what we do when we multiply an integer by zero  :)
So the **decimal** library does the thing that ***is*** explicitly specified:

- The coefficient of the result, before rounding, is computed by multiplying together the coefficients of the operands.
- The exponent of the result, before rounding, is the sum of the exponents of the two operands.
- The sign of the result is the exclusive or of the signs of the operands.

**Question:** what is the need to return the coefficient and exponent (i.e, 0E-28) if one of the operands is a zero? We already know what that coefficient is when calling the multiplication function. Why not just return zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raymond Hettinger](https://github.com/rhettinger) has given a comprehensive explanation at [cpython github](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99604):

In [Arithmetic Operations](https://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html), the section on Arithmetic operations rules tells us:

> Trailing zeros are not removed after operations.

There are test cases covering multiplication by zero. Here are some from multiply.decTest:

```
-- zeros, etc.
mulx021 multiply  0      0     ->  0
mulx022 multiply  0     -0     -> -0
mulx023 multiply -0      0     -> -0
mulx024 multiply -0     -0     ->  0
mulx025 multiply -0.0   -0.0   ->  0.00
mulx026 multiply -0.0   -0.0   ->  0.00
mulx027 multiply -0.0   -0.0   ->  0.00
mulx028 multiply -0.0   -0.0   ->  0.00
mulx030 multiply  5.00   1E-3  ->  0.00500
mulx031 multiply  00.00  0.000 ->  0.00000
mulx032 multiply  00.00  0E-3  ->  0.00000     -- rhs is 0
mulx033 multiply  0E-3   00.00 ->  0.00000     -- lhs is 0
mulx034 multiply -5.00   1E-3  -> -0.00500
mulx035 multiply -00.00  0.000 -> -0.00000
mulx036 multiply -00.00  0E-3  -> -0.00000     -- rhs is 0
mulx037 multiply -0E-3   00.00 -> -0.00000     -- lhs is 0
mulx038 multiply  5.00  -1E-3  -> -0.00500
mulx039 multiply  00.00 -0.000 -> -0.00000
mulx040 multiply  00.00 -0E-3  -> -0.00000     -- rhs is 0
mulx041 multiply  0E-3  -00.00 -> -0.00000     -- lhs is 0
mulx042 multiply -5.00  -1E-3  ->  0.00500
mulx043 multiply -00.00 -0.000 ->  0.00000
mulx044 multiply -00.00 -0E-3  ->  0.00000     -- rhs is 0
mulx045 multiply -0E-3  -00.00 ->  0.00000     -- lhs is 0
```

And this from the examples:

```
mulx053 multiply 0.9 -0 -> -0.0
```

In the Summary of Arithmetic section, the motivation is explained at a high level:

> The arithmetic was designed as a decimal extended floating-point arithmetic, directly implementing the rules that people are taught at
> school. Up to a given working precision, exact unrounded results are
> given when possible (for instance, 0.9 ÷ 10 gives 0.09, not
> 0.089999996), and trailing zeros are correctly preserved in most operations (1.23 + 1.27 gives 2.50, not 2.5). Where results would
> exceed the working precision, floating-point rules apply.

More detail in given in the FAQ section [Why are trailing fractional zeros important?](https://speleotrove.com/decimal/decifaq1.html#tzeros).